# How to hide a program from Linux's tab-completion

Tags: linux, command-line, path, tab-completion

I have an account on a shared machine, and cannot access /usr/bin, where there are many programs which I never use.

I'd like tabbing to ignore many of these programs. For example, I'd like `on<TAB>` to complete to `oneprog`, but there are other matches.

```
~> on
on_ac_power           oneprog          onto2vocabularyclass
```

Is there a way to hide the other two matches, short of creating a mirror of /usr/bin?

Comment: If you can't access `/usr/bin` just remove it from your `$PATH` and then bash shouldn't autocomplete from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)...

You can define your own autocomplete rules for options/arguments, using `complete`. You can define filename suffices that are ignored in arguments by exporting variable `$FIGNORE`.

However, I don't think you can alter the way Bash resolves program names.

You could, of course, `alias` the program you want to run, so you don't have to type so much:

```
[me@host ~]$ alias on=oneprog
[me@host ~]$ on
```

You *could* (if you were feeling silly) alias the Bash builtin, `command` and use `complete` to define the arguments it will accept (your list of nice programs), and then always remember to type your alias before your real command.

```
[me@host ~]$ alias run=command
[me@host ~]$ complete -W "ls cd" run
[me@host ~]$ run ls
```

See also *[How to have autocomplete ignore a specific completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12694)*.

Comment: Thanks, that link was especially useful. As much as I'd normally keep pushing, my reaction to "don't do it, just use an alias" seems to be identical to the author of the linked question, who eventually accepted the answer.